# Adding Time Limit For a Download Link

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, http

How can I Add Time Limit To My Download Link .

Suppose That There is a Download link such : http://www.mywebsite.com/mygallery.zip

I Want to tell users , You can download This File just for 5 hours.and after 5 hours link will disabled.

What is the best thing to do?

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Is the site data driven? Is there a record in your DB (or can there be) that represents the download?

Comment: maybe yes .  there is a field which contains the time in hours.Can I fill my database and that field every hours![To Decrease it automatically.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this many times by generating a guid and expiration time and mapping them to the actual file location. This can be done in a database or an xml file, or however you want to do it.

The link would end up looking something like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/getFile.aspx?id=0C65942EF7BE43892DE1DEEE00B51858

Then you just write a page that serves up the file by looking up the guid, comparing the expiration time and if it's all good, serve the file to the browser.

It's simple and can be greatly improved upon, but the concept is sound.

Good luck!

Comment: A guid is a Globally Unique Identifier. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/trobbins/archive/2004/11/22/268176.aspx) is a good explanation for you.